# React Router v6.10 - changing route loses state of previous page

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, react-router

So I'm fairly new to React and I'm now learning about routing. I created a simple app where I have two pages (Home and Todos) and I route between them through a Tab Bar. On one page I have a list where I can add data to it through events. Code is:

App.tsx

```
const router = useNavigate();
return (
    <div className='app-main-cont'>
      <div className='app-main-content'>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Navigate replace to='/home'/>}></Route>
          <Route path='/home' element={<Home/>}></Route>
          <Route path='/todos' element={<Todos/>}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </div>

      <nav className='tab-bar'>
        <div className='tab' onClick={()=>{router('/home')}}>HOME</div>
        <div className='tab'  onClick={()=>{router('/todos')}}>TODOS</div>
      </nav>


    </div>

  )
```

Todos.tsx

```
function Todos() {

  const [todosList, addNewTodo] = useState<TodoClass[]>([]);
  const [inputValue, changeInputValue] = useState('');

  const handleChangeEvent = (event: ChangeEvent) => {
    const val = (event.target) as HTMLInputElement;
    changeInputValue(val.value);
  }

  const handleAddTaskButtonClick = (event: any) => {
    let obj: TodoClass = {name: inputValue};
    addNewTodo([...todosList, obj]);
  }
    
  return (
    <div className='todos-cont'>
      <div className='list'>
        {todosList.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <div className='list-item' key={index}>
                {item.name}
              </div>
            )
          })}
      </div>

      <div className='add-todo'>
          <div className='input-todo'>
            <input type="text" placeholder='Input a todo task' onChange={handleChangeEvent} />
          </div>
          <div className='add-btn' onClick={handleAddTaskButtonClick}>
            ADD
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Now the problem is that when I add data to the list, go to Home and then get back to the Todos page through the navbar, the data that I added before is lost. Why is that? Am I missing something? Thanks!
(The same thing using Ionic-React is not happening that's why I suppose that I am missing something)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `todos` state is only local state in the `Todos` component, and when you navigate from `"/todos"` to `"/home"` the todos route is no longer matched so the `Todos` component unmounts. React state is not persisted.

You could lift the `todos` state up to a common ancestor that remains mounted regardless of what route is matched and pass the state down as props.

Example:

```
const navigate = useNavigate();

const [todosList, addNewTodo] = useState<TodoClass[]>([]);

const addTodo = (todo: TodoClass) => {
  addNewTodo(todos => [...todos, todo]);
};

return (
  <div className='app-main-cont'>
    <div className='app-main-content'>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Navigate replace to="/home" />} />
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
        <Route
          path="/todos"
          element={(
            <Todos
              todosList={todosList}
              addTodo={addTodo}
            />
          )}
        />
      </Routes>
    </div>

    <nav className='tab-bar'>
      <div className='tab' onClick={() => router("/home")}>HOME</div>
      <div className='tab'  onClick={() => router("/todos")}>TODOS</div>
    </nav>
  </div>
);
```

```
interface TodosProps {
  todosList: TodoClass[];
  addTodo: TodoClass => void;
}

function Todos({ addTodo, todoList }: TodosProps) {
  const [inputValue, changeInputValue] = useState('');

  const handleChangeEvent = (event: ChangeEvent) => {
    const val = (event.target) as HTMLInputElement;
    changeInputValue(val.value);
  }

  const handleAddTaskButtonClick = (event: any) => {
    addTodo({ name: inputValue });
  }
    
  return (
    <div className='todos-cont'>
      <div className='list'>
        {todosList.map((item, index) => (
          <div className='list-item' key={index}>
            {item.name}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>

      <div className='add-todo'>
        <div className='input-todo'>
          <input type="text" placeholder='Input a todo task' onChange={handleChangeEvent} />
        </div>
        <div className='add-btn' onClick={handleAddTaskButtonClick}>
          ADD
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

An alternative might also be to persist the local `todosList` state to localStorage, and initialize the state from localStorage. When the component is mounted the `todosList` state is set to the persisted value or the initial state value `[]`. Use a `useEffect` hook to persist state to localStorage when it updates.

Example:

```
function Todos() {
  const [todosList, addNewTodo] = useState<TodoClass[]>(() => {
    // Return persisted state value or default initial value
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todosList")) ?? [];
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (todosList) {
      // Persist todosList state to localStorage
      localStorage.setItem("todosList", JSON.stringify(todosList));
    }
  }, [todosList]);

  ...
    
  return (
    ...
  );
}
```